# Python pandas - read_sql > How To delete column names from pandas

Tags: python, pandas

This is the data imported into the query:

```
    result_pandas = pd.read_sql(query, connection)
    print(result_pandas)
```

[image]

I want to delete the top row:

```
typenum    level  ratio_normal  ratio_tour  status
```

How to delete it?

This is the data I want. It doesn't mean changing the name, it means deleting it completely.

NOT result_pandas.columns = ['', '', '', '', '']

[image]

Comment: Do you want to change the name of the column? Or remove all the column names? Don't understand the ask

Comment: I want to remove the Column name.

Comment: Then how are you going to reference the data in each column? Whats the end goal?

Comment: In the column name, it means typenum , level, ratio_normal, ratio_tour, status....
I want to print only 4 lines of internal data excluding column names.

Comment: My goal is to write only the data, excluding the column names, into a Google spreadsheet.

Comment: you want the output to just show 4 rows of data without the column name? Is that the ask?

Comment: That's right!!!

Comment: Thats simple, when you write the file to google spreadsheet, you can give `df.to_csv('filename.csv', header = False)`. It will exclude the header row

Comment: I'll try this. Thank you.!!!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We could use some context why you are trying to do this. The whole point of working with DataFrames is to be able to reference columns and rows. If you do not need this you can convert to a numpy array:

```
df.to_numpy()
```

All together:

```
df = pd.DataFrame([[238,1,10],[238,2,10],[238,3,1]], columns=['x','y','z'])
data = df.to_numpy()
print(f"Data as array without labels: \n{data}")
print(f"Print row 3 column 2: \n{data[2,1]}")
```

With output:

```
Data as array without labels: 
[[238 1 10] 
[238 2 10] 
[238 3 1]] 
Print row 3 column 2: 
3
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to write to a csv file and dont want to have the header in the row,

then try this:

```
df.to_csv('filename.csv', header = False)
```

The output will be rows without the header row.